# Trouble understanding the output involving Distinct

Tags: sql

I'm struggling to understand why these two statements are giving the same output:

Case 1:

```
SELECT sum(DISTINCT prod_price) 
FROM PRODUCTS
```

Case 2:

```
SELECT SUM(SQ.COST)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [VEND_ID] as PROD,[PROD_PRICE] as COST FROM PRODUCTS) SQ
```

where my output for `SELECT * FROM Products` looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Think about this query

```
SELECT SUM(SQ.COST)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [VEND_ID] as PROD,[PROD_PRICE] as COST 
      FROM PRODUCTS) SQ
```

AS

```
SELECT DISTINCT [VEND_ID] as PROD,[PROD_PRICE] as COST FROM PRODUCTS
```

going into temp table say named as SQ with two columns:

- VEND_ID
- PROD_PRICE

This query is going to be evaluated first and then the next part of query like:

```
SELECT SUM(SQ.COST)
FROM SQ
```

Which is nothing but same as your original query and hence same answer.

Comment: @RADAR Thanks :) Glad it helps someone to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 distinct `product_price` and `vend_id` combination in your Product table.

Coincidentally, if I only take `product_price`, then also there are 6 distinct records:

```
3.49
5.99
8.99
11.99
4.99
9.49.
```

Hence the sum is same